# Calculate trend in dataframe using previous row's values and polyfit

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find a way to calculate a rolling trend in a dataframe with Python.

In my sample below the x values are used to calculate the trend. The polyfit trend should be calculated using a 3 row rolling window (current row + previous 2 rows). The m column is the slope of the polyfit output. Finally, I'd like to add another new column that indicates if the slope is greater than a certain value.

```
   x m   m > 1
1  3 nan False
2  5 nan False
3  5 1   False
4  7 1   False
5  9 2   True
6  9 1   False
```

Here is a pseudo-code attempt of what I'm trying to do. My difficulty is getting the previous 2 row values and then passing them into the polyfit function, which returns two values: m and c.

```
df['m > 1'] = np.where(np.polyfit(index[-3], x[-3], 1) > 1), True, False)
```

Comment: you mean current row + prev 2 rows ?

Comment: yep, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with myself. Perhaps there's a more elegant solution using rolling().

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calculate_trend(values, steps):
    if len(values) == 0:
        return 0, 0

    x = np.arange(1, steps + 1, 1)
    y = values
    m, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    return m, c

data = [[1,3],
        [2,5],
        [3,5],
        [4,7],
        [5,9],
        [6,9],]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index', 'x'])

df['m'] = 0
m_position = df.columns.get_loc('m')
df['m_check'] = False
m_check_position = df.columns.get_loc('m_check')
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if i >= 3:
        x_range = df.iloc[i-2: i+1]['x'].values
        m, c = calculate_trend(x_range, len(x_range))
        df.iat[i, m_position] = m
        if (m > 1):
                df.iat[i, m_check_position] = True
```